# ng-model binds data in one view but not the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm using ui-router to build multiple views, I have a typical header, content, footer layout.

I used to have a search box in the content template, it simply uses ng-model to capture user input:

```
            <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                Search: <input ng-model="searchPattern">
            </label>
```

Then I use angular filter to search in my data in the same content view.

However, if I move these lines to the "header" view, it no longer works, it seems data bound by ng-model doesn't travel through views? I have specified the same controller for both views, i.e.:

```
.state('app', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: 'header.html',
                    controller: 'MyController'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'content.html',
                    controller: 'MyController'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: 'footer.html',
                }
            }
        })
```

and I can print out {{searchPattern}} in the header view itself, but not in content view.

So how do I capture data in view and use it to filter in another view?

Answer (score 0):

You should not reuse controllers, it's ideal to have a controller be used only with a specific template.

What you can do is create a service, and put your data in there, then inject them in the two controllers where you want your data to be shared